# Magento 2.3 Configurable Product drop down price calculated wrong

Tags: configurable-product, magento2.3, magento2.3.0, configurable-product-options

The base comparison price for a configurable product seems to be the cheapest price excluding tax.
Then the extra price added by the each configurable product in a Magento 2.3 dropdown is calculated including tax.
This makes even the cheapest option appear as it has an extra cost, which is only the tax.

See the screenshot below where the actual price of option "Test 1" is $62.50, but option "Test 1" still appears to be $12.50 more expensive than the cheapest/base alternative. the +$12.50 shouldn't be there, since its already the cheapest alternative.

[image: Configurable product dropodown]

Comment: Which attribute was this? I'm having a similar issue.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/152632)

Comment: I had a custom product attribute added that was supposed to be used on other products. This was by default selected on this product as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this was because I had another product attribute that was automatically selected on this product. When I removed that other attribute, the tax in the drop down disappeared.