# Configurable prices just show the tax

Tags: magento2.3, magento2.3.1

I am having the same problem on 2.3.1 as described here:

[Magento 2.3 Configurable Product drop down price calculated wrong](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/256834/magento-2-3-configurable-product-drop-down-price-calculated-wrong/257594#)

In that thread a product attribute is mentioned. Does anyone know what attribute that is? It seems to be a general problem as others experience the same thing.